# Android Action Bar Custom View Navigation Indicator hidden

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, custom-view

I'm adding a custom view to the action bar but when I do the navigation indicator icon is not displayed. When I don't display the custom view, the indicator shows up and works fine.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(navConf.getBackgroundDraw()));

    if (0 != navConf.getActionBarCustomView()){
        getActionBar().setCustomView(navConf.getActionBarCustomView());
        getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
                | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    }

    try{
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                navConf.getDrawerIcon(),
                navConf.getDrawerOpenDesc(),
                navConf.getDrawerCloseDesc()
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(AbstractNavDrawerActivity.this);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(AbstractNavDrawerActivity.this);
            }
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("ActionBarDrawerToggle: ", ex.toString());
    }

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.icon_menu);
    getActionBar().setCustomView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_main, null),
            new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                    ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    Gravity.CENTER
            )
    );
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.mipmap.icon_menu, //nav menu toggle icon
            0, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            0 // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Maybe you want to write some additional words for this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add this flag as an ActionBar display option:

```
ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP
```